# Azure VPS lose port inbound policy every time subnet gets associated in another VPS

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, azure-networking

I'm having a weird issue but I understand is caused by my lack of knowledge on how Azure manages network policies about inbount/outbound rules across VPS. Let me depict my scenario:

I have 2 VPS, one for Gitlab, the other for JIRA. In Gitlab I need port 10022 to be open for our git server, in JIRA vps I need to have port 8080 open for JIRA itself.

In each Network Interface section of each of those VPS I created the appropiate Inbound rules for these ports. Then, reading some documentation from Microsoft on this regard, I went to Network Security group -> Subnet and associated with a virtual network and a subnet. The images below showcase this for one of the VPS.

[image]

[image]

If I press Ok, I can then use the port in this VPS with no issues (10022), but then JIRA becomes unavailble in the other VPS. Then I go back to the other VPS -> Network Interfaces -> Network Security Group -> Subnets and I notice there is nothing associated, I select the same virtual network and subnet I selected in the images above. Then JIRA works BUT, port 10022 on gitlab VPS is not available....checking the VPS from gitlab, I see that subnet is empty.

It just looks like each VPS needs its own subnet with its own set of inbout/outbound rules? Or can I associate one subnet from one virtual network to several VPS? This is confusing, some help here will be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, you had better not configure NSG rules on your subnet in your scenario.Because your two VMs are in the same subnet, but need to open different ports. You could configure NSG rules in your VM Network interfaces.
[image]

Please refer to this [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-nsg-arm-portal#manage-associations) about how to manage NSG (associate NSG to NIC)

**Notes: NSG could associate to VM and subnet.**

Comment: not sure I understand your solution...that seems to be exactly what I was doing so far...Right now I fixed it by opening ports on the general Network Security group (the one that applies to all VPS) and opening both ports in that one and associating it to my only subnet. This is not optimal as it exposes ports in all VPS...

Comment: Yes, it's not security. I suggest you create two NSG rules, one associates to VPS, another associates to JIAR. You could set your subnet NSG rule is none.

Comment: Hi, please refer to the following link about how to associate NSG to a VM nic.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-manage-nsg-arm-portal#manage-associations